# How to get exclusive count in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R:

```
DF <- tibble::tribble(
    ~ID, ~Check,
  "I-1",   "A1",
  "I-2",   "A2",
  "I-2",   "OT",
  "I-2",   "LP",
  "I-3",   "A1",
  "I-3",   "A2",
  "I-4",     NA,
  "I-5",     NA,
  "I-6",   "A1",
  "I-6",   "OT",
  "I-7",   "A2"
  )

DF2 <- tibble::tribble(
    ~ID,     ~Remarks,
  "I-1", "{X1,XR,XT}",
  "I-2",    "{X2,XR}",
  "I-3",           NA,
  "I-4", "{X1,XR,X2}",
  "I-5",       "{X1}",
  "I-6",       "{XT}",
  "I-7",    "{X1,X2}"
  )
```

Using the above mentioned two dataframe, I need the output in the following format:

Where I want to identify the exclusive count of `Check` and `Remark` for each unique ID and combination of each `Check` with another `Check` and similar with `Remark`.

Note - The order of rows should be highest to lowest based on `Exclusive_Count` of `Check`. It is quite possible that the number of unique `Check` and `Remark` may differ in my actual dataframe. (i.e 10 unique `Remark` and 5 `Check`, something like this)

DF_Output<-

```
Remark   Exclusive_Count  %       X1  X2  XR  XT  Check  Exclusive_Count  %          A1  A2  OT  LP
Blank    1               33.33%   0   0   0   0   Blank  2                50.00%     0   0   0   0
X1       1               33.33%   0   2   2   1   A1     1                25.00      0   1   1   0
X2       0               0.00%    2   0   1   0   A2     1                25.00%     1   0   1   1
XR       0               0.00%    2   2   0   1   OT     0                0.00%      1   1   0   1
XT       1               33.33%   1   0   1   0   LP     0                0.00%      0   1   1   0
Total    3               100.00%  5   4   4   2   Total  4                100.00%    2   3   3   2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Btw, ***please*** be cognizant of the tags that the Stack recommendation system gives you: I see nothing in here about graphics, so [tag:ggplot2] seems superfluous (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: There only one `Blank` for `Remarks` why you have `Exclusive_count` for `Blank` is `2`?

Comment: @SinhNguyen: Sorry, It was my bad...corrected it.

Comment: What rules define that `Blank` remark is align with `Blank` Check, `X1` remark align with `A1` Check, and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do what you're looking for... Likely not the most succinct, but seems to do the trick.

```
# Load Library
library('tidyverse')

### CHECK ###
# Load Check Table
DF <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Check,
  "I-1",   "A1",
  "I-2",   "A2",
  "I-2",   "OT",
  "I-2",   "LP",
  "I-3",   "A1",
  "I-3",   "A2",
  "I-4",     NA,
  "I-5",     NA,
  "I-6",   "A1",
  "I-6",   "OT",
  "I-7",   "A2"
)

# Count by ID
DF <- DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(count = n())

# Count by Check
DF_X <- DF %>% dplyr::filter(count ==  1) %>%
  group_by(Check) %>%
  dplyr::summarize("Count" = sum(count))

# Identify unique values of Check
DF_UNIQUE <- unique(DF$Check)
DF_FIN <- data.frame("Check" = DF_UNIQUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Join Counts by Check with unique list of Checks
DF_FIN <- left_join(x = DF_FIN, y = DF_X, by = "Check")

# Replace NA's with zeros
DF_FIN[is.na(DF_FIN$Count),2] <- 0

# Calculate Percentages
DF_FIN <- DF_FIN  %>%
    mutate("Check Percentage" = `Count`/sum(`Count`))

# Rename Columns
colnames(DF_FIN) <- c("Check", "Exclusive Count", "Check Percentage")

# Replace NA value with the word "BLANK"
DF_FIN[is.na(DF_FIN$Check),1] <- "BLANK"

# Sort by Exclusive Count and then by Check (alphabetical)
DF_FIN <- DF_FIN %>%
  arrange(desc(`Exclusive Count`), Check)

# Join Checks to itself and count instances
DF_CHECKS <- full_join(x = DF, y = DF, by = "ID")

DF_CHECKS <- DF_CHECKS %>%
  group_by(Check.x, Check.y) %>%
  dplyr::summarize("N" = n())

DF_CHECKS_SPREAD <- DF_CHECKS %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Check.y, values_from = N)
check_order <- DF_CHECKS_SPREAD$Check.x
check_order[is.na(check_order)] <- 'NA'
DF_CHECKS_SPREAD <- DF_CHECKS_SPREAD %>% select(check_order)

# Set the diagonal to zeros
for (i in 1:nrow(DF_CHECKS_SPREAD)){
  DF_CHECKS_SPREAD[i,i+1] <-0
}

# Rename Columns
colnames(DF_CHECKS_SPREAD)[1] <- "Check"
colnames(DF_CHECKS_SPREAD)[colnames(DF_CHECKS_SPREAD) == "NA"] <- "BLANK"

# Drop the BLANK column
DF_CHECKS_SPREAD$BLANK <- NULL

# Replace NA value with the word "BLANK"
DF_CHECKS_SPREAD[is.na(DF_CHECKS_SPREAD$Check),1] <- "BLANK"

# Replace all other NA's with zero
DF_CHECKS_SPREAD[is.na(DF_CHECKS_SPREAD)] <- 0

# Join the two Checks data sets together & calculate grand totals
FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS <- left_join(x = DF_FIN, y = DF_CHECKS_SPREAD, by = "Check")
FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS <- FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS %>%
  bind_rows(summarise(.,
                      across(where(is.numeric), sum),
                      across(where(is.character), ~"Total")))


### REMARKS ###
# Load Remarks table
DF2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,     ~Remarks,
  "I-1", "{X1,XR,XT}",
  "I-2",    "{X2,XR}",
  "I-3",           NA,
  "I-4", "{X1,XR,X2}",
  "I-5",       "{X1}",
  "I-6",       "{XT}",
  "I-7",    "{X1,X2}"
)

# Remove the {} from the Remarks string
DF2$Remarks <- str_replace_all(string = DF2$Remarks, c("\\{" = "", "\\}" = ""))

# Expand string into rows
DF2 <- separate_rows(DF2, Remarks, convert = TRUE)

# Group and count by ID
DF2 <- DF2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(count = n())

# Count by Remarks
DF2_X <- DF2 %>% dplyr::filter(count ==  1) %>%
  group_by(Remarks) %>%
  dplyr::summarize("Count" = sum(count))

# Identify unique Remarks
DF2_UNIQUE <- unique(DF2$Remarks)
DF2_FIN <- data.frame("Remarks" = DF2_UNIQUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Join count of Remarks with unique list of Remarks
DF2_FIN <- left_join(x = DF2_FIN, y = DF2_X, by = "Remarks")

# Replace NA's with zeros
DF2_FIN[is.na(DF2_FIN$Count),2] <- 0

# Calculate Percentages
DF2_FIN <- DF2_FIN  %>%
  mutate("Remarks Percentage" = `Count`/sum(`Count`))

# Rename columns
colnames(DF2_FIN) <- c("Remarks", "Exclusive Count", "Remarks Percentage")

# Replace NA value with the word "BLANK"
DF2_FIN[is.na(DF2_FIN$Remarks),1] <- "BLANK"

# Sort by Exclusive Count and then by Check (alphabetical)
DF2_FIN <- DF2_FIN %>%
  arrange(desc(`Exclusive Count`), Remarks)

# Join Remarks to itself and count instances
DF_REMARKS <- full_join(x = DF2, y = DF2, by = "ID")
DF_REMARKS <- DF_REMARKS %>%
  group_by(Remarks.x, Remarks.y) %>%
  dplyr::summarize("N" = n())
DF_REMARKS_SPREAD <- DF_REMARKS %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Remarks.y, values_from = N)
check_order <- DF_REMARKS_SPREAD$Remarks.x
check_order[is.na(check_order)] <- 'NA'
DF_REMARKS_SPREAD <- DF_REMARKS_SPREAD %>% select(check_order)

# Set the diagonal to zeros
for (i in 1:nrow(DF_REMARKS_SPREAD)){
  DF_REMARKS_SPREAD[i,i+1] <-0
}

# Rename Columns
colnames(DF_REMARKS_SPREAD)[1] <- "Remarks"
colnames(DF_REMARKS_SPREAD)[colnames(DF_CHECKS_SPREAD) == "NA"] <- "BLANK"

# Drop the BLANK column
DF_REMARKS_SPREAD$BLANK <- NULL

# Replace NA value with the word "BLANK"
DF_REMARKS_SPREAD[is.na(DF_REMARKS_SPREAD$Remarks),1] <- "BLANK"

# Replace all other NA's with zero
DF_REMARKS_SPREAD[is.na(DF_REMARKS_SPREAD)] <- 0

# Join the two Remarks data sets together & calculate grand totals
FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS <- left_join(x = DF2_FIN, y = DF_REMARKS_SPREAD, by = "Remarks")
FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS <- FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS %>%
  bind_rows(summarise(.,
                      across(where(is.numeric), sum),
                      across(where(is.character), ~"Total")))

# Count Rows in Check and Remarks dataframes and add rows in dataframe
# with less rows to match # of rows in other.
checkRows <- nrow(FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS)
remarksRows <- nrow(FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS)
rowDiff <- abs(checkRows - remarksRows)

if(checkRows < remarksRows){
  cat("Adding", rowDiff , "rows to the Checks dataframe.\n\n")
  FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS[nrow(FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS)+rowDiff,] <- NA
  FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS[nrow(FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS),] <- FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS[checkRows,]
  FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS[checkRows,] <- NA
}else if(remarksRows < checkRows){
  cat("Adding", rowDiff , "rows to the Remarks dataframe.\n\n")
  FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS[nrow(FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS)+rowDiff,] <- NA
  FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS[nrow(FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS),] <- FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS[remarksRows,]
  FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS[remarksRows,] <- NA
}else{
  print("There is no difference in number of rows between Checks and Remarks.\n\n")
}


# Combine columns from Checks and Remarks into one table.
RESULTS <- cbind(FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS, FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS)
RESULTS$`Check Percentage` <- paste(round(100*RESULTS$`Check Percentage`,2), "%", sep="")
RESULTS$`Remarks Percentage` <- paste(round(100*RESULTS$`Remarks Percentage`,2), "%", sep="")
RESULTS
```

Comment: @C Jeruzal - Thanks, getting error at `spread` function. Error is `Error in DF_CHECKS %>% spread(Check.y, N) : 
  could not find function "spread"`

Comment: @user9211845 - yeah, I forgot that `spread` was retired from `tidyr` package.  I updated the code to use `tidyr::pivot_wider` instead.  That should work for you now.

Comment: I also added a column sort after the `pivot_wider` since column positions changed.  Now they should match the desc. order of the Remarks or the Checks.

Comment: Also added the total percentage calc and adjusted percentage columns names.

Comment: @C Jeruzal - Thanks a lot, I'm getting an error at `RESULTS <- cbind(FINAL_TABLE_REMARKS, FINAL_TABLE_CHECKS)` because number of rows are differ. How can I `cbind` in differ number of rows?

Comment: If the quantity of Checks (5 quantity) and Remarks (5 quantity) match, as they did in your reprex, then you'll be able to use the column bound (`cbind`) RESULTS dataframe.  If they do not match, you won't be able to `cbind` unless you add a row to the dataframe with less rows. In the case where row counts don't match you could add a blank row above the "Totals" row in the dataframe with less rows and then the `cbind` will work.

Comment: @user9211845, I added the ability to handle an unequal number of Checks and Remarks (e.g. 5 qty Checks, 10 qty Remarks) to the code.  Now it will add blank rows to pad the smaller dataframe so the two dataframes can be column bound.

Answer (score 6):

The OP has requested a *canonical answer*. So, I have created a *function* `get_exclusive_counts()` which takes the first two columns of any tibble, data.frame, or data.table where the first column contains *IDs* and the second column contains the *payload*, e.g., `Check`, in long format.

The function is independent of column names and will work with an arbitrary number of different items in the *payload* column. It returns a data.table for each input tibble:

```
get_exclusive_counts(DF)
```

> ```
>     Check Exclusive_Count       % A1 A2 LP OT
> 1:  Blank               2  50.00%  0  0  0  0
> 2:     A1               1  25.00%  0  1  0  1
> 3:     A2               1  25.00%  1  0  1  1
> 4:     LP               0   0.00%  0  1  0  1
> 5:     OT               0   0.00%  1  1  1  0
> 6: Totals               4 100.00%  2  3  2  3
> ```

For the second use case `DF2`, the *payload* needs to be split into separate rows beforehand:

```
library(magrittr)
DF2 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Remarks = stringr::str_remove_all(Remarks, "[{}]")) %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(Remarks) %>% 
  get_exclusive_counts()
```

> ```
>    Remarks Exclusive_Count       % X1 X2 XR XT
> 1:   Blank               1  33.33%  0  0  0  0
> 2:      X1               1  33.33%  0  2  2  1
> 3:      XT               1  33.33%  1  0  1  0
> 4:      X2               0   0.00%  2  0  2  0
> 5:      XR               0   0.00%  2  2  0  1
> 6:  Totals               3 100.00%  5  4  5  2
> ```

Note that the name of  the first column of the result table has been retained from the input data.frame.

The OP has mentioned that the number of `Remarks` and `Check` may differ. Therefore, it doesn't really make sense to `cbind()` the two result tables because this only will give a reasonable result in case the number of rows is the same.

Also, OP's expected result has some column names repeated (at least `Exclusive_Count`, `%`, perhaps more) which indicates that the result may not be used for further processing but for display / print only.

### Printing results side by side

However, I have created a function `get_exclusive_counts_side_by_side()` which prints the results from calling `get_exclusive_counts()`

- for an arbitray number of input datasets,
- with differing numbers of rows, and
- with the last rows (`Totals`) aligned.

The function returns a data.table with character columns.

The call below will reproduce OP'S expected result:

```
get_exclusive_counts_side_by_side(
  DF2 %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(Remarks = stringr::str_remove_all(Remarks, "[{}]")) %>% 
    tidyr::separate_rows(Remarks),
  DF)
```

> ```
>    Remarks Exclusive_Count       % X1 X2 XR XT  Check Exclusive_Count       % A1 A2 LP OT
> 1:   Blank               1  33.33%  0  0  0  0  Blank               2  50.00%  0  0  0  0
> 2:      X1               1  33.33%  0  2  2  1     A1               1  25.00%  0  1  0  1
> 3:      XT               1  33.33%  1  0  1  0     A2               1  25.00%  1  0  1  1
> 4:      X2               0   0.00%  2  0  2  0     LP               0   0.00%  0  1  0  1
> 5:      XR               0   0.00%  2  2  0  1     OT               0   0.00%  1  1  1  0
> 6:  Totals               3 100.00%  5  4  5  2 Totals               4 100.00%  2  3  2  3
> ```

Here is another use case to demonstrate that it will work with differing rows and an arbitrary number of input datasets:

```
get_exclusive_counts_side_by_side(
  DF, 
  DF3 %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(Remarks = stringr::str_remove_all(Remarks, "[{}]")) %>% 
    tidyr::separate_rows(Remarks),
  DF)
```

> ```
>     Check Exclusive_Count       % A1 A2 LP OT Remarks Exclusive_Count       % X1 X2 XR XT Y2 Y3 Y4  Check Exclusive_Count       % A1 A2 LP OT
> 1:  Blank               2  50.00%  0  0  0  0      X1               2  50.00%  0  2  2  1  1  1  0  Blank               2  50.00%  0  0  0  0
> 2:     A1               1  25.00%  0  1  0  1   Blank               1  25.00%  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     A1               1  25.00%  0  1  0  1
> 3:     A2               1  25.00%  1  0  1  1      XT               1  25.00%  1  0  1  0  0  0  0     A2               1  25.00%  1  0  1  1
> 4:     LP               0   0.00%  0  1  0  1      X2               0   0.00%  2  0  2  0  0  0  0     LP               0   0.00%  0  1  0  1
> 5:     OT               0   0.00%  1  1  1  0      XR               0   0.00%  2  2  0  1  0  0  0     OT               0   0.00%  1  1  1  0
> 6:                                                 Y2               0   0.00%  1  0  0  0  0  1  1                                         
> 7:                                                 Y3               0   0.00%  1  0  0  0  1  0  0                                         
> 8:                                                 Y4               0   0.00%  0  0  0  0  1  0  0                                         
> 9: Totals               4 100.00%  2  3  2  3  Totals               4 100.00%  7  4  5  2  3  2  1 Totals               4 100.00%  2  3  2  3
> ```

### Function definitions

The code looks rather bulky but half of the lines are comments. So, the code should be fairly self-explanatory.

Also, about half of the lines of code are due to OP's additional requirements, like a *%* column or a *Totals* row.

```
get_exclusive_counts <- function(DF) {
  library(data.table)
  library(magrittr)
  # make copy of first 2 cols to preserve original attributes of DF
  DT <- as.data.table(DF[, 1:2])
  # retain original column names
  old <- colnames(DT)[1:2]
  # rename colnames in copy for convenience of programming
  setnames(DT, c("id", "val")) # col 1 contains id, col 2 contains payload
  # aggregate by id to find exclusive counts = ids with only one element
  tmp <- DT[, .N, keyby = id][N == 1L]
  # create table of exclusive counts by joining and aggregating
  excl <- DT[tmp, on = .(id)][, .(Exclusive_Count = .N), keyby = val] %>% 
    # append column of proportions, will be formatted after computing Totals
    .[, `%` := Exclusive_Count / sum(Exclusive_Count)]
  # anti-join to find remaining rows
  rem <- DT[!tmp, on = .(id)]
  # create co-occurrence matrix in long format by a self-join
  coocc <-   rem[rem, on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE] %>% 
    # reshape to wide format and compute counts of co-occurrences w/o diagonals
    dcast(val ~ i.val, length, subset = .(val != i.val))
  # build final result table by merging both subresults
  merge(excl, coocc, by = "val", all = TRUE) %>% 
    # replace NA counts by 0 
    .[, lapply(.SD, nafill, fill = 0L), by = val] %>% 
    # clean-up: order by decreasing Exclusive_Counts %>% 
    .[order(-Exclusive_Count)] %>% 
    # append Totals row
    rbind(., .[, c(.(val = "Totals"), lapply(.SD, sum)), .SDcols = is.numeric]) %>% 
    # clean-up: format proportion as percentage
    .[, `%` := sprintf("%3.2f%%", 100 * `%`)] %>% 
    # clean-up: Replace <NA> by "Blank" in val column
    .[is.na(val), val := "Blank"] %>%
    # rename val column
    setnames("val", old[2]) %>% 
    # return result visibly
    .[]
}
```

Here is the code for `get_exclusive_counts_side_by_side()`:

```
get_exclusive_counts_side_by_side <- function(...) {
  library(data.table)
  library(magrittr)
  # process input, return list of subresults
  ec_list<- list(...) %>% 
    lapply(get_exclusive_counts)
  # create row indices for maximum rows
  rid <- ec_list %>% 
    lapply(nrow) %>%
    Reduce(max, .) %>% 
    {data.table(.rowid = 1:.)}
  # combine subresults 
  ec_list %>% 
    # insert empty rows if necessary
    lapply(function(.x) .x[
      , .rowid := .I][
        # but align last row
        .rowid == .N, .rowid := nrow(rid)][
          rid, on =.(.rowid)][
            , .rowid := NULL]
    ) %>%  
    # all data.tables have the same number of rows, now cbind()
    do.call(cbind, .) %>% 
    # replace all NA by empty character strings
    .[, lapply(.SD, . %>% as.character %>% fifelse(is.na(.), "", .))]
}
```

### Additional explanation

If I understand correctly, *exclusive counts* refers to *IDs* which have only of one item (or `NA`) assigned to it. This is fairly straight forward to compute by

1. counting the number of items per *ID*,
2. picking the *IDs* with only one item,
3. picking the rows in the input data.frame which belong to those *IDs* (using a join), and
4. counting the appearances of the items in the subset of *exclusive rows*.

Furthermore, the function deals with OP's additional requirements which go beyond the identification of *exclusive counts*:

- adding a matrix of *co-occurrence counts* of the remaining, non-exclusive
  rows,
- adding a column of proportions of exclusive counts at a specific position and formatting it as percent,
- adding a *Totals* row,
- replacing `NA`s by zero or `"Blank"`, resp.

### Data

```
DF <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Check,
  "I-1",   "A1",
  "I-2",   "A2",
  "I-2",   "OT",
  "I-2",   "LP",
  "I-3",   "A1",
  "I-3",   "A2",
  "I-4",     NA,
  "I-5",     NA,
  "I-6",   "A1",
  "I-6",   "OT",
  "I-7",   "A2"
)

DF2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,     ~Remarks,
  "I-1", "{X1,XR,XT}",
  "I-2",    "{X2,XR}",
  "I-3",           NA,
  "I-4", "{X1,XR,X2}",
  "I-5",       "{X1}",
  "I-6",       "{XT}",
  "I-7",    "{X1,X2}"
)

DF3 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,     ~Remarks,
  "I-1", "{X1,XR,XT}",
  "I-2",    "{X2,XR}",
  "I-3",           NA,
  "I-4", "{X1,XR,X2}",
  "I-5",       "{X1}",
  "I-6",       "{XT}",
  "I-7",    "{X1,X2}",
  "I-8", "{X1,Y2,Y3}",
  "I-9",    "{Y2,Y4}",
  "I10",       "{X1}",
)
```